# UIPageViewController bug when using camera

Tags: ios, camera, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a Snapchat like feature where the views are navigated by the user swiping left or right. I'm using a UIPageViewController for this.

There is a problem though when I slide onto a UIImagePickerController view. The camera displays properly as the user is sliding onto that view, however when the user lets go of the screen and the view locks into place the camera fully blurs almost as if a fog layer is applied to it and then refocuses back to normal.

The weird thing is this doesn't occur if the transition style is "Page Curl". It only happens on "Scroll".

How can I stop this behaviour?

4 View Controllers in storyboard - Master, PageView, Home and Create (code for master and create below)

Thanks.

HeroMasterViewController class:

```
partial class HeroMasterViewController : ViewControllerBase IUIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    private UIViewController[] _heroViewControllers;

    private UIPageViewController _heroPageViewController;

    public HeroMasterViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle, Navigation.Page.HeroMaster)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        _heroPageViewController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("HeroPageViewController") as UIPageViewController;

        _heroPageViewController.DataSource = this;

        InitViewControllers ();

        var startingViewController = new UIViewController[1] { _heroViewControllers [0] };

        _heroPageViewController.SetViewControllers (startingViewController, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, null);

        _heroPageViewController.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height);

        this.AddChildViewController (_heroPageViewController);

        this.View.AddSubview(_heroPageViewController.View);

        _heroPageViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
    }

    public void InitViewControllers()
    {
        _heroViewControllers = new UIViewController[2];

        _heroViewControllers [0] = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("HomeViewController");

        _heroViewControllers [1] = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("CreateViewController");
    }


    public UIViewController GetPreviousViewController (UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var controller = referenceViewController as HeroViewControllerBase;

        if (controller.Index == 0)
            return null;

        return _heroViewControllers[controller.Index - 1];
    }

    public UIViewController GetNextViewController (UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var controller = referenceViewController as HeroViewControllerBase;

        if (controller.Index == (_heroViewControllers.Length - 1))
            return null;

        return _heroViewControllers[controller.Index + 1];
    }
}
```

CreateViewController class:

```
partial class CreateViewController : HeroViewControllerBase
{
    private Xamarin.Media.MediaPicker Picker;
    private MediaPickerController MediaController;


    public CreateViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle, Navigation.Page.HeroCreate, 1)
    {
        this.Picker = new Xamarin.Media.MediaPicker();

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        DisplayPicker ();
    }

    private void DisplayPicker()
    {
        if (this.MediaController != null)
            return;

        this.MediaController = this.Picker.GetTakePhotoUI(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Name = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() + ".jpg",
                Directory = "MediaPickerSample"
            });

        this.MediaController.AllowsEditing = false;
        this.MediaController.ShowsCameraControls = false;
        this.MediaController.AllowsImageEditing = false;

        this.MediaController.CameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front;


        this.MediaController.View.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height);
    var translate = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation (0, 71.0f);

        this.View.AddSubview(this.MediaController.View);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: @RickSmith see above, have added.